# A JTree node changes its representation after the second mouse click

Tags: java, swing, tostring, jtree

I have recognized that each time I initiate the second LEFT mouse click on a node it changes it's representation to the `toString()` value of its object.

Under the object I mean the second parameter of the method:

```
getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus)
```

It's not necessarily a double click. The pause between two clicks can be several minutes.
When after that I click on another node, the value changes back to its previous value.

Has anybody faced the same problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made your tree editable, but you didn't specify any editor for the tree. So it uses the default editor, which uses the `toString()` method of your ContentNode to edit the node.

You probably don't want your tree to be editable.

Comment: Yes, I don't use an editor. But the nodes are represented as I want till the second click. Do I need an editor to resolve the problem? I think I know what you mean. I should use setEditable(false);